# Can't deprecate NPM package from GitHub Packages because of absent version.ID

Tags: npm, github-packages

My team has an NPM package e.g. `@team/old-eslint-config`.

Recently we have decided that we can deprecate it in favour of another package.

But whenever I try to deprecate it with the following command:

```
npm deprecate @team/old-eslint-config@1.0.0 "package is deprecated, use @team/eslint-config-new"
```

I get an error:

```
400 Bad Request - PUT {package_url} - unmarshalling packument failed: version.ID cannot be empty
```

Also the same error is thrown on unpublish attempt:

```
npm unpublish @team/old-eslint-config@1.0.0
```

I have noticed that if I get package info using `npm view` that "_id" is empty:

```json
{
  "_id": "",
  "name": "@team/old-eslint-config",
  "dist-tags": {
    "latest": "1.0.1"
  },
```

But if I view some other package, for example `npm view express --json | head -10`, I get an id for it:

```json
{
  "_id": "express@4.18.2",
  "_rev": "4045-d8d4b4e069d1cd062e776a86681bcf2d",
  "name": "express",
  "description": "Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework",
```

Can I deprecate/unpublish package from GitHub Packages? Do I need to set `_id` for my package? If so, how do I do that?

I have also tried:

- to log in/log out
- to publish package new versions - this succeeds so that means I have write access to it
- to add both `id` and `_id` to `package.json` and then unpublish newly created version - it still throws an error. I can't unpublish or deprecate it. `npm view` returns no `_id`.

Comment: Hey, I got the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @RémiBecheras unfortunately no, I have decided to mark it as deprecated in README.md and in description and that's it